# Is it possible to copy a section from one form into another form within the same user account?

Tags: cognito-forms

In other words, I have already created a somewhat complicated section in one form that I would like to insert into another existing form. However, if I select copy in the field options of one form, when I open the other form, it does not give me the option to paste.

Is there a way to do this without recreating the whole section in the other form?

Answer (score 1):

I'm a developer with [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com/).

We do not offer a way to copy a field out of one Cognito Form, and place it in another Cognito From. The best way to do this would be to copy the full Cognito Form, and then build around the section or field that you want in the new form.